# Cassandra Upgrade from pre-1.1 resulting in Exception when migrating sstables

Tags: cassandra

I'm attempting to upgrade from 1.0.12 to 1.1.0 with the aim of then upgrading to a newer version.  I understand that I must stagger the upgrade and bounce from one major to another and so this is our first step in that chain.

I've a ring of 4 nodes on 1.0.12 and have followed the following steps (note, this is all in test env).

- Have the new version of Cassandra and have merged the yaml files.
- Have edited the env.sh for max heap and Xss size.
- Have taken a backup of the tables / schema.
- Proceeded to drain the node that I'm upgrading.
- Confirmed node is in a down state for the rest of the ring.
- Stopped the Cassandra process and confirmed no longer running.
- Started the Cassandra service from the new binary of 1.1.0

After starting Casandra I shortly receive this Exception and I'm not sure sure how to resolve it.  Might anyone be able to shed any light?  I've checked all logs that I can find but they are echoing this output.

```
 INFO 09:54:02,208 JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
 INFO 09:54:02,216 Loading settings from file:/opt/apache-cassandra-1.1.0-rc1/conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 09:54:02,299 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO 09:54:02,429 Global memtable threshold is enabled at 2362MB
 INFO 09:54:02,441 EC2Snitch using region: us-east, zone: 1d.
 INFO 09:54:02,531 Upgrade from pre-1.1 version detected: migrating sstables to new directory layout
ERROR 09:54:02,535 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1954)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories.migrateFile(Directories.java:534)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories.migrateSnapshots(Directories.java:503)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories.migrateSSTables(Directories.java:485)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.setup(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.activate(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:353)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:106)
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1954)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories.migrateFile(Directories.java:534)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories.migrateSnapshots(Directories.java:503)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories.migrateSSTables(Directories.java:485)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.setup(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.activate(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:353)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:106)
Exception encountered during startup: String index out of range: -1

[1]+  Exit 1                  $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cassandra
```